# SQL: Count column x if column y = z

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to count customers that are contactable via different channels. The following code will give me a single count of only the customers contactable via SMS.

```
with grouping as (
select  distinct                        
case when sms_correct_flag = 'Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end as smsable,                      
case when email_correct_flag = 'Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end as emailable,                  
case when address_correct_flag = 'Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end as dmable,           
contact_key                     
from raw.contacts                   
)

select count(distinct contact_key)
from grouping 
where smsable = 'Y';
```

I'd like to end up with a table with 'Channel' as a column, 'Email', 'SMS', 'DM' as rows, and their respective customer counts filled.

This may be a count(case when....) but can't figure out how to make that work when we're checking the case for a column that is not the same as the column we are counting.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I suspect you're solution will be something along the lines of HAVING as opposed to WHERE.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have only three channels, you can use `UNION ALL` to produce the results that you need:

```
with grouping as (
    select
        MAX(case when sms_correct_flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as smsable
    ,   MAX(case when email_correct_flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as emailable
    ,   MAX(case when address_correct_flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as dmable
    ,   contact_key
    from raw.contacts
    group by contact_key
)
select 'sms' as channel, SUM(smsable) as cust_count from grouping
union all
select 'email' as channel, SUM(emailable) as cust_count from grouping
union all
select 'dm' as channel, SUM(dmable) as cust_count from grouping
```

**Note:** I do not know if Amazon's redshift has built-in pivot facilities. If it does, you may have a better approach than this poor man's pivot implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select channel,                        
       sum(case when sms_correct_flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as smsable,                      
       sum(case when email_correct_flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as emailable,                  
       sum(case when address_correct_flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as dmable          
from raw.contacts  
group by channel;
```

Comment: I think `channel` is a "synthetic" field that OP wants to produce. I think he's looking for a pivot, but I have no idea if redshift offers a way to do it.